# Linear search not returning expected output

Tags: python, linear-search

I am tring a simple linear search in python but it is not working and i can not find what is wrong with my code!!!

```
n = input("enter a number: ")
arr = [1,42,3,45,5]
count = 0;
for i in range(0, len(arr)):
    if(arr[i] == n):
        count = count + 1
if(count>0):
    print("found")
else:
    print("not found")
```

Comment: `arr[i] == int(n)` `input` returns string

Comment: also don't use len to loop over the same list, simply use `for i in arr: if i == int(n): count += 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is this line `if(arr[i] == n):`: `n` is of type `str` so the comparison to an `int` will always fail.

Try:

```
if arr[i] == int(n):
```

Here, you are casting `n` to an integer before the comparison. Please note that this will throw an error if you cannot cast to an `int`. You could solve this as follows:

```
n = input("enter a number: ")
arr = [1, 42, 3, 45, 5]

try:
    if int(n) in arr:
        print("found")
    else:
        print("not found")

except ValueError:
    print("Not an integer")
```

Comment: that is a great approach thanks man i was doing a silly mistake I should casting user input into int

Comment: @SouvikSen Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.